# Can I format regular expressions in multiple lines in R?

Tags: r, regex

An answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958628/regex-expression-for-yyyymmdd-nnnn) included a Regular Expression in this format.

```
# match any year
([0-9]{4})
(
  # January-September
  (?:0[1-9])
  # OR October - December
  |(?:1[0-2])
)
(
  # First nine days of the month.
  (?:0[1-9])
  # Next twenty days of the month.
  |(?:[1-2][0-9])
  # Last two days of the month.
  |(?:3[0-1])
)
# A hyphen and then any four digits.
-([0-9]{4})
```

This coding style makes regular expressions so much clearer for development and reading. Is there a way to do this in R?

When I copy that pattern into a variable it doesn't work in R because the variable looks like this.

```
 "\n# match any year\n([0-9]{4})\n(\n  # January-September\n  (?:0[1-9])\n  # OR October - December\n  |(?:1[0-2])\n)\n(\n  # First nine days of the month.\n  (?:0[1-9])\n  # Next twenty days of the month.\n  |(?:[1-2][0-9])\n  # Last two days of the month.\n  |(?:3[0-1])\n)\n# A hyphen and then any four digits.\n-([0-9]{4})\n# Last two days of the month. Excludes February.\n  |(?:(?<!02)3[0-1])"
```

**That** doesn't work.

I'm sure it's possible to write an R function that does a reverse `grep` to take out the comment lines and strips out the new line characters. But is there already a native way to do that? Or is that an enhancement for the `stringr` package, or something?

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for pointing me to your answer in a previous question. Another collaborator and I even duplicated our duplicates! But this is a beautiful tip that revolutionizes my Regular Expression development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn on free-spacing regular expressions start the regular expressoin with the modifier `(?x)` and specify `perl=TRUE`.  Here is an example where the whitespace in the regular expression between `a` and `b` is ignored.

```
grep("(?x)a
     b", c("ab", "a b", "a\nb", "ab"), perl = TRUE)
## [1] 1 4
```